# How to build entitymentions from tokens tagged by the `regexner` annotator?

Tags: stanford-nlp

This question is similar to [Can I get an entityMention from the result of a TokensRegex match in Stanford CoreNLP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52450768/10559668)

I have a set of TokensRegex rules that tag tokens with a different tag than the standard "LOCATION", "PERSON" etc.

The `entitymentions` annotator is very useful for multi-token named entities. How can I also build entitymentions for token sequences that are tagged by the `regexner` annotator? They don't appear to be built with standard settings.

I'm using CoreNLP 3.9.2 with the http API

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example command

```
java -Xmx5g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner -ner.additional.tokensregex.rules example.rules -file example.txt -outputFormat text
```

Some more info...The `ner` annotator will run a series of steps

1. statistical ner
2. numeric sequences and SUTime
3. fine-grained NER (example: LOCATION --> STATE_OR_PROVINCE)
4. additional TokensRegexNER rules
5. additional TokensRegex rules
6. entity building

So after steps 1-5 are run, the entities will be built, and will see tags from your TokensRegex rules.

This is in the current GitHub code and version 3.9.2 (won't work with older versions).

More info here: https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/ner.html